# Splitting a string, and assigning to fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, split

I have a fairly simple issue. When my page is loaded it generates a long string which represents and address, for example:

```
101, Dalmations Avenue, Miami, Florida, USA, 908343
```

Using jQuery, i am able to split the string using:

```
var address = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;

var houseNumber = address.split(",")[0];
var street      = address.split(",")[1];
var district    = address.split(",")[2];
var county      = address.split(",")[3];
var country     = address.split(",")[4];
var postalcode  = address.split(",")[5];
```

I then need to asign the split values to fields within my html, which onload, are delcared as:

```
<input type="hidden" name="ADDR_HOUSENUMBER" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="ADDR_STREET" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="ADDR_DISTRICT" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="ADDR_COUNTY" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="ADDR_COUNTRY" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="ADDR_POSTALCODE" value="">
```

I was under the impression i could assign my split values like:

```
document.forms[0].ADDR_HOUSENUMBER[01].value = houseNumber;
```

Is this correct?

Thanks

Comment: you should cache computed values you reuse in variables: `var fields = address.split(","); var houseNumber = fields[0] //... and so on`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Using Javascript. Check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C6ZJU/)

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="ADDR_HOUSENUMBER" value="" />
<input type="text" name="ADDR_STREET" value="" />
<input type="text" name="ADDR_DISTRICT" value="" />
<input type="text" name="ADDR_COUNTY" value="" />
<input type="text" name="ADDR_COUNTRY" value="" />
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var address = "101, Dalmations Avenue, Miami, Florida, USA, 908343";

var houseNumber = address.split(",")[0];
var street = address.split(",")[1];
var district = address.split(",")[2];
var county = address.split(",")[3];
var country = address.split(",")[4];
var postalcode = address.split(",")[5];

document.getElementsByName("ADDR_HOUSENUMBER")[0].value = houseNumber;
```

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
var address = '101, Dalmations Avenue, Miami, Florida, USA, 908343'; //sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;

var $ins= $('input[type="hidden"][name^="ADDR"]');
$.each(address.split(/\s*,\s+/), function(i, val){
    $ins.eq(i).val(val)
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/MfdLV/)

Note: It depends on the order of input fields so if you change them it will give wrong results

---

If you don't want to be depended on the order then

```
var address = '101, Dalmations Avenue, Miami, Florida, USA, 908343'; //sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;

var order = ["ADDR_HOUSENUMBER", "ADDR_STREET", "ADDR_DISTRICT", "ADDR_COUNTY", "ADDR_COUNTRY", "ADDR_POSTALCODE"];
$.each(address.split(/\s*,\s+/), function (i, val) {
    $('input[name="' + order[i] + '"]').val(val)
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/MfdLV/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Add class-attribute to your html.

```
<input type="hidden" class="ADDR_HOUSENUMBER" name="ADDR_HOUSENUMBER" value="">
<input type="hidden" class="ADDR_STREET" name="ADDR_STREET" value="">
<input type="hidden" class="ADDR_DISTRICT" name="ADDR_DISTRICT" value="">
<input type="hidden" class="ADDR_COUNTY" name="ADDR_COUNTY" value="">
<input type="hidden" class="ADDR_COUNTRY" name="ADDR_COUNTRY" value="">
<input type="hidden" class="ADDR_POSTALCODE" name="ADDR_POSTALCODE" value="">
```

Then set the value of them with

```
$(".ADDR_HOUSENUMBER").val(houseNumber);
```

etc...

Answer (score 1):

Do not split the string each time. Split it once and re-use later. You may want something like below:

```
var address = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
var vals = address.split(",");

var houseNumber = vals[0];
var street      = vals[1];
...
...


document.forms["yourFormName"].elements["ADDR_HOUSENUMBER"].value = houseNumber;
...
...
```