# How can I split a string separated with pipe symbol using jQuery regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a dynamically generated string which is basically a row with each value separated by a pipe symbol `|`, I need to separate it and insert them into a bunch of hidden fields .

[This was almost what I needed to do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22555182/splitting-a-string-and-assigning-to-fields), but not working for me, and I can only use (`~` or `|`) as special characters since my data may contain other characters.

Here is my code:

```
var data = "Val1@#|val2$%|val3(*|"; // dynamically generated 

$.each(data.split(/\s*|\s+/), function(i, val) {
    alert(val);
});
```

Comment: Why don't you just do `Data.split('|')`? That will give you an array of the values (and an empty String as last value since your String ends with '|').

Comment: its ok without regex, but i was trying to learn regex so just a wish , but need a solution any how :-(.

Comment: @AmarnathRShenoy YOU WANT TO LEARN, START FROM REGEXONE

Comment: So escape `|` in regex as in Aziz Shaikh's answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use this:

```
var Data ="Val1@#|val2$%|val3(*|" //dynamically generated 
alert(Data);
$.each(Data.split(/\|/), function (i, val) {
     alert(val);
})
```

Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nLdcr/

Comment: the second argument in `each` is a `function`, what does that mean ?

Comment: @MrX fourth empty value is returned because the input contains "|" in the end. Use this updated fiddle to avoid empty value: http://jsfiddle.net/nLdcr/1/

Answer (score 8):

`"Val1@#|val2$%|val3(*|".split('|')` works fine. There's no need for regex.
The equivalent with regex would be: `.split(/\|/)`.

Comment: THank you , do this belong to regex ??

Comment: @AmarnathRShenoy buddy why do you want to kill a fly with a sword ??

Comment: @aelor: Killing a fly with a sword is actually pretty impressive

Answer (score 6):

No need for regex:

```
var list = Data.split("|");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `|` for seperating your string, you can use the normal `string.split()`function of javascript. There is no need to use a regex for this.

HTML:

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

Code:

```
var data = "Val1@#|val2$%|val3(*|";

$.each(data.split('|'), function(key, value){
    $('#result').append(value).append('<br/>');
});
```